# Will this generate a dynamic HTML table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to generate a table with Javacript dynamically  by passing the size of the table.  This table is an n by n table.

```
  funtion createTable(n) {
        var body = getElementByTag('body');
        var table = document.createElment('table');
        table.setAttribute("border","1px solid #ccc");

        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            var row = table.insertRow(i);
            for (j=0;j<n;j++){
                var cell= row.insertCell(j);
            }
        }
    }
```

I cannot get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some syntax errors and you need to add the table to the DOM.

```
  function createTable(n) {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.setAttribute("border","1px solid #ccc");
        body.appendChild( table );
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            var row = table.insertRow(i);
            for (j=0;j<n;j++){
                var cell= row.insertCell(j);
            }
        }
    }

   createTable(10);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nwofk5dx/

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was in class.  :).  Again, Thanks a lot!